# Sending message to telegram in influxdb

Tags: telegram-bot, influxdb, flux

I'm trying to follow this example https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0/stdlib/contrib/sranka/telegram/message/.

My query is almost the same:

```
import "contrib/sranka/telegram"
token = "TOKEN"

lastReported =
      from(bucket: "system_stats")
        |> range(start: -1m)
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "mem")
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "used_percent")
        |> last()

telegram.message(token: token, channel: "xxx", text: "Test ${lastReported._value}")

lastReported
```

But I get the following error: `type error @11:68-11:80: expected {A with _value:B} but found [{C with _value:D, _time:time, _stop:time, _start:time, _measurement:string, _field:string}]`

this is how data looks like (we can see `_value` column):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I am using InfluxDB v2

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I used the old version (2.0) of influx db. After upgrade to 2.7 everything works